# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ diverge or converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Does the series $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ diverge or converge?

When I try to solve it I use the limit comparison test. It all works well when I compare it to the function $\frac{1}{n^2}$. The result of the limit comparison is 1 and that means the series converges.

My problem is that when I compare the series to the series $\frac{1}{n}$ I also get 1 which means that the series diverges. It's impossible obviously and I think that I am calculating one of the limits wrong.

Comment: Indeed, one of the limits you computed is wrong. If you show your computations, we could tell you where the mistake is.

Comment: @Xoque55 yes. sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Just do a direct comparison. Clearly $0<\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n^2+1}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\sum 1/n^2$ is known to be convergent series, you are done.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Could you please show me how to take the limit to infinity of n/(n*sqrt((n^2)+1))?

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to see it is to note that your series is $$\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$$
Since the latter converges, so does yours

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the Limit Comparison Test against $ \ \frac{1}{n} \ $ will be misleading, as

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{n}{n \ \sqrt{n^2 + 1}} \ = \ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{1}{ \ \sqrt{n^2 + 1}} \ = \ 0 \ ,  $$

but the conclusions for this Test are only meaningful when the limit gives a *non-zero* constant.  Application of the LCT requires a judicious selection for comparison series, as you found when comparison *versus* $ \ \frac{1}{n^2} \ $ gave you a limit "at infinity" of 1 .

Answer (score 0):

Use the comparison test (for always positive series) to compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. We can see $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n^2+1}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ because $n\sqrt{n^2+1}>n^2$$ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Props to @Jason for solving in the comments (didn't see).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check is to use the Integral test:
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2+1}}
 = \left. \ln \frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}} \right|_1^\infty
 = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{2}} < \infty
$$
so the series must also converge.